# C/C++ - What are Tringular Array and Sparse Array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix

i really wondering what exactly are Triangular Array and Sparse Array. i have been looking in google but there is no article i found. only discussion and they not talking about the basic. thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

There are wikipedia pages on them.

[Sparse array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array) and [Triangular array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_array)

A **sparse array** is one in which most of the cells of the array are initialized to null or 0. In such cases we waste a lot of memory. That is why, we generally replace a sparse array with a linked list and when a new cell gets initialized to a non-null value, we just create a node and add the corresponding links properly to reconstruct to linked list. A sparse array is one in which more than 70 percent of the array has null(0) values. When we know that an array is going to be sparse, we generally replace it with a more memory efficient linked list.

A Triangular array is a special kind of a 2-D array where the ith row contains i number of elements. The most simple example is a Pascal's triangle.

```
 1
 1 1
 1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
 1 4 6 4 1
```

[nCr = (n-1)C(r-1) + (n-1)C(r)].

So, a[i][j] = a[i-1][j-1] + a[i-1][j]. So a Triangular array helps in the construction of the Pascal's Triangle.

Hope this helps!!